# Postfix virtual_mailbox_maps mysql lookup on 2 different DBs

Tags: mysql, postfix

I'm trying to configure a postfix server to receive email for 2 different domains (no problem so far). But the users/mailboxes for both domains need to be looked up in 2 different tables on 2 different MySQL server.

Example:

- Domain example1.org lookup in table users on DB FOO.example1.org
- Domain example2.org lookup in table customers on DB BAR.example2.org

I haven't been able to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify many mysql maps in [`virtual_mailbox_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_mailbox_maps) parameter. For your example case, here the configuration

```
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/example1,mysql:/etc/postfix/example2
```

Then in both maps specify the different parameters

```
#/etc/postfix/example1
user = someone
password = some_password
hosts = foo.example1.org
dbname = foodb
query = SELECT mailbox FROM users

#/etc/postfix/example2
user = theotherone
password = different_password
hosts = bar.example2.org
dbname = bardb
query = SELECT mailbox FROM customers
```

Consults the official documentation of postfix [mysql_table](http://www.postfix.org/mysql_table.5.html) for more information.